# Advanced indexing in 2d tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have a 2d tensor X. and two lists of indexes that is first index and second call a and b. I want to do

`X[a[i],b[i]] = 0 for i in range(len(a))`

How can I do this. If i directly do `X[a,b]` the error is IndexError: The advanced indexing objects could not be broadcast

Answer (score 2):

Check your `lists` which contains the indices, some values might be out of range. That's when you will get **IndexError** like the one below:

> In [43]: X[4,4]
>
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 X[4,4]
>
> IndexError: index 4 is out of range for dimension 0 (of size 3)

If your indices are in correct range, it should work fine.

Here is an example:

```
In [35]: X = torch.Tensor([[3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 3, 2, 1]])

In [36]: X
Out[36]: 

 3  4  5  6
 1  2  3  4
 6  3  2  1
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x4]

In [37]: a = [0, 2]

In [38]: b = [1, 2]

In [39]: X[a, b]
Out[39]: 

 4
 2
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2]

In [40]: X[a, b] = 0

In [41]: X
Out[41]: 

 3  0  5  6
 1  2  3  4
 6  3  0  1
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x4]
```